# C# - How can I get the key and value from strings of xaml resourcedictionary format?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I read the xaml file as binaryreader and have it as a string.

And,

```
<System: String x: Key = "ABC"> AAAA </ System: String>
.........................many
<System: String x: Key = "ZZZ"> ASDQWE </ System: String>
```

I want to get ABC and AAAA as a String.

Whether there is a parser or method that can have this type of list ??

This is my xaml file to string code

```
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes((int)file.InputStream.Length);
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
```

Comment: Better use [`XamlReader.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You haven't posted any example XAML file. But assuming you actually do have a XAML file that's a resource dictionary, you can use `XamlReader` as @Clemens says, which will return your `ResourceDictionary` object, already parsed, and then you can use the members of the `ResourceDictionary` object to retrieve the keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the file line by line and extracted it using regular expressions.

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream);
    string textLine = reader.ReadLine();
    string key = GetKeyStringFromXaml(textLine);
    string val = GetValStringFromXaml(textLine);
    public string GetKeyStringFromXaml(string textLine) {
        Regex regex = new Regex("<System:String x:Key=\"(.*)\">(.*)</System:String>");
        var v = regex.Match(textLine);
        return v.Groups[1].ToString();
    }
    public string GetValStringFromXaml(string textLine) {
        Regex regex = new Regex("<System:String x:Key=\"(.*)\">(.*)</System:String>");
        var v = regex.Match(textLine);
        return v.Groups[2].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Xaml` file is a `xml` file. So you can easily use `LinqToXml` to select the nodes and values.